# Flux deployment issue

Tags: amazon-eks, flux

I am triggering a pipeline and there is buildspec file which contains image build command and also after build and image is pushed to ecr and also with help of AWS Signer and platform type "notation " the image is getting signed and stored in ECR. Now The deployment is done with FLUXCD and image is deployed on EKS but all the images are deployed whether they are signed or not. And there is Gatekeeper and ratify in EKS for validating the image but flux deploy all the images. So, I need help in how I can modify or setup flux so that it check and deploy only the signed image stored in ECR not every image with the tag specified in image policy.

So can you help me regarding this issue?
Hope I give all details and if any more information is required please let me know.

I tried implementing gatekeeper in EKS but didn't work flux is deploying both signed and unsigned image.

Answer (score 0):

In FluxCD, an ImageRepository resource is used to set up FluxCD to listen for changes in the specific image registry.

Assuming your FluxCD setup has ImageRepository resource. You can use its exclusionList configuration to exclude certain images.

```
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: ImageRepository
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: apps
spec:
  interval: 1h
  image: docker.io/org/image
  exclusionList:
    - "^.*\\.sig$"
    - "1.0.2"
    - "1.1.1|1.0.0"
```

For more information:
[ImageRepository - exclusionList](https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/image/imagerepositories/#exclusion-list)

Comment: But we are signing the image with help of notatation and AWS signer profile. So image tag does not contain .sig. So to verify image is sign or not we can use gatekeeper or kyverno. But how flux will know that image is signed and need to deploy.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your flux source controller? is it HelmRepository or GitRepository?

Comment: We are using GitRepository not Helm. And we are using image policy, image registry and image automation for deployment of ECR images in EKS